# *ngIf returns false yet still displays content in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Perhaps there is something wrong with my code that I am unaware of, but for some reason when I `console.log(this.enabled)` I get false. Allow my code to explain.

Here is my folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Here are the important files

1. App Component TS
2. APP Component HTML
3. Shopping-list TS
4. Shopping-list HTML
5. Recipe-list TS
6. Recipe-list HTML

App Component HTML:

```html
<!-- Header emits an event that is either "shopping" or "recipe." Saves it in the $event -->
<app-header
(toggleRequest) = "toggleRequest($event)">
</app-header> 

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12"> 

            <!--  -->
            <app-receipe-list
            [enabled] = "enableRecipe">
                <!-- Saves enabled in the receipe-list component (wrong spelling) -->
            </app-receipe-list>
            <app-shopping-list
            [enabled] = "enableShopping">
                <!-- Saves enabled in the shopping-list component -->
            </app-shopping-list>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

2. AppComponent TS

```js
  // both initally do not display anything
  enableRecipe = false
  enableShopping = false

  // when one is being displayed, the other should be hidden.
  toggleRequest(event) {
    if (event === "shopping")  {
      this.enableShopping  = true
      this.enableRecipe = false
    }
    else {
      this.enableRecipe = true
      this.enableShopping  = false
    } 
  }
```

3. Shopping-list HTML

```html
<div class="container" (click) = "display()" *ngIf="enabled">
     <!-- The display function is a test function that shows the value of enabled. I click and it shows false
    yet the shopping-list is still displayed underneath -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <app-shopping-list-edit></app-shopping-list-edit>
        <hr>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" style="cursor: pointer;" *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
            {{ingredient.name}} ({{ingredient.amount}})</a>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

4. Shopping-list TS

```js
  @Input() enabled: boolean

  // display() shows false yet when I put enabled in ngIf, the HTML still renders.
  display() {
    console.log(this.enabled)
    console.log("shopping")
  }
```

5. Recipe-list HTML

```html
<div class="container" (click) = "display()" *ngIf="enabled">
    <!-- Here, it works perfectly, but I do not know the difference between "receipe-list" and "shopping-list" -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <app-recipe-item *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" [recipe] = "recipe"></app-recipe-item>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <app-recipe-detail></app-recipe-detail>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

6. Finally, recipe List TS

```js
// As you can see, very similar code!
@Input() enabled: boolean
display() {
  console.log(this.enabled)
  console.log("recipe")
}
```

What happens is that when I click on "shopping list" in the following picture, I get the folllowing.
[image: Clicked on shopping list]

And when I click on "Recipes", I get the following.
[image: When I click on Recipes]

As you can see, the shopping went underneath the recipes, but I do not want that, I want the shopping to disappear. When I try to use *ngIf, it does not work for some reason :(

Comment: Move your logic up. Your shopping list and recipe list components shouldn’t be concerned with if they’re enabled or not, your app template should not render them if it doesn’t want to - i.e. put your ngIf around the components in the app template